# getting total count for Facebook objects

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm currently using rubygems, fbgraph for my application to pull data from facebook.

everything is working well, but now i would want to get the total count of the object(e.g. photos, videos) that i'm pulling. is there any way to do so?